# Java Runtime#halt() does not stop the JVM

Tags: java, halt

This is a client/server application using RMI. Once a RMI request is received by the server for destroy() - I need to abort the VM. I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0)` for this purpose. But after the call to halt() the VM still exists and the only way I can kill it is by using `Force Kill` on OSX.

The stacktrace for the calling thread is as follows:

```
"RMI TCP Connection(3)-192.168.1.4" daemon prio=5 tid=7f99a7103000 nid=0x11d467000 runnable [11d464000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Shutdown.halt0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.halt(Shutdown.java:95)
    - locked <7f44c90d0> (a java.lang.Shutdown$Lock)
    at java.lang.Runtime.halt(Runtime.java:256)
    at net.sourceforge.marathon.runtime.JavaRuntime.destroy(JavaRuntime.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sourceforge.rmilite.impl.RemoteInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandlerImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

What may be the issue?

Comment: isn't thee a SecurityManager which forbids the Shut Down?

Comment: Any reason not to call `System.exit()`?

Comment: @matheszabi no. In that case halt is supposed to throw an exception. This just hangs.

Comment: I can't call System.exit() - this particular case the shutdown hooks and finalizers should not be called. That said, System.exit() also exhibits the same behavior. The final call (native) to halt0 does not return.

Comment: Looks like networking over some socket is involved, could you try to close that socket first?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas I am using RMI and don't have access to the sockets in this part of code. I was under the impression that Runtime#halt() should always close the JVM. I will check this on Linux/Windows and see how they behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried multiple things to make this work.

1. Added `Runtime#runFinalization` before the call to halt().
2. Invoked `halt()` in `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`
3. Invoked `halt()` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

None of these worked. Finally,

1. Invoked `halt()` in a timer task using `Timer#schedule`

This worked and is consistently working till now. Thanks to everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the destroy() command, you should:

1. Unexport all remote objects.
2. Unexport any Registries.
3. Clear any static references to remote objects and registries.

The JVM will then exit automatically, unless you have any non-daemon threads executing.

Comment: I moved away from this implementation (not using RMI anymore in marathon) - but it wasn't this simple. The way the system is structured, the part where this code is executed doesn't have access to **any** thing. I just needed to do an `abort` of the VM.